# Check if position (Latitude Longitude) is within KML polygon

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables, point-in-polygon

I am planning a data visualisation. But there is one big questionmark I need to clarify in advance.

Let's say I have a Fusion Table containing several Latitude, Longitude positions. And furthermore I have a map with KML polygons.

How can I check if a Lat/Lng position is within a specific polygon? So that I get back true or false.

Thank you very much in advance.
All the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fusion Tables offers spatial queries. This [example](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/search_and_zoom) and the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#spatial) have more details.